# TeamCity and External Database - Which One Works Best, SQL Server or Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, teamcity

I'm evaluating TeamCity, and am using it with HSQLDB.

Now, I'm ready to use an external database, and I have the option to use either Oracle or SQL Server.

Everything being equal, Oracle is the preferred option due to corporate policy.

Which database will give me the smoothest experience together with TeamCity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the vendor express a preference? Do they support both fully?

Do you have licences for either database server?

Do you have capacity within an existing installation?

Which product is your support team most comfortable with? Sounds like it might be Oracle...

Comment: Due to the support issues you mention, I tried with Oracle (10g), and it works like a charm :-)